# How to parse json sub arrays having the same names inside the main array coming from a web service in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I want to populate spinners from json data coming from a web service. I have a main array named as "categoriesList" which includes sub-arrays named as "subcategories" but these arrays have the same names and contain objects of data. I want to populate the 2nd spinner of subcategories based on the selection of 1st spinner i.e categoriesList. The problem is that when I select an item from 1st spinner(categoriesList) then the 2nd spinner displays all the sub arrays but i need only the respective subarray to display in 2nd spinner(subcategories).

**Following is the json data format:**

```
{
"success": true,
"code": 200,
"message": "Data  Found.",
"content": {
    "companyTypes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Distributor"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Mechanics"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Retailer"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Others"
        }
    ],
    "citiesList": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sharja"
        }
    ],
    "brandsList": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Test Brand"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Brand 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Brand 3"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Brand 4"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "Brand 5"
        }
    ],
    "categoriesList": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Test Category",
            "subCategories": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "sub category 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "title": "Sub Category 5"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Category 2",
            "subCategories": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "Sub Category 2"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "title": "Sub Category 3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Category 3",
            "subCategories": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "title": "Sub Category 4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

**And this my android java code:**

**categoryList code**

```
public void populateSpinnerCategories() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlConfigurationsCategories,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        HashMap<String, String> map;

                        jsonObjectResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        jsonObjectContent = jsonObjectResponse.getJSONObject("content");

                        jsonArrayCompanyTypes = jsonObjectContent.getJSONArray("categoriesList");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayCompanyTypes.length(); i++) {
                            jsonObjectID = jsonArrayCompanyTypes.getJSONObject(i);

                            distributorId = jsonObjectID.getInt("id");

                            title = jsonObjectID.getString("title");

                            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put("title", title);
                            map.put("id", distributorId + "");
                            myArrList.add(map);

                            //Log.i("Rsp", "onResponse: " + distributorId + "------Title: " + title);
                        }

                        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
                        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), myArrList, R.layout.activity_show,
                                new String[]{"title"},
                                new int[]{R.id.tv_column_name});
                        spinnercategoriesList.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

                        spinnercategoriesList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                selectedCompanyType = myArrList.get(position).get("title").toString();

                                categoryId = (int) (spinnercategoriesList.getSelectedItemId() + 1);

                                //populateCompanies(DIST_ID);

                                //TODO populate the subcategories spinner
                                populateSpinnerSubCategories(categoryId);

                                loadCategories();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(request);
}
```

**SubCategory code**

```
public void populateSpinnerSubCategories(final int categoryId) {

    String url = "http://radial-energy.com/radial/api/configurations";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        HashMap<String, String> map;

                        String subCategory = null;
                        int subCatId = 0;

                        jsonObjectResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        jsonObjectContent = jsonObjectResponse.getJSONObject("content");

                        JSONArray jsonArrayCategories = jsonObjectContent.getJSONArray("categoriesList");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayCategories.length(); i++) {
                            jsonObjectID = jsonArrayCategories.getJSONObject(i);

                            JSONArray jsonArraySubCategories = new
                                    JSONArray(jsonArrayCategories.getJSONObject(i)
                                    .getString("subCategories"));

                            System.out.println("Sub Categories Array: " + jsonArraySubCategories);

                            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArraySubCategories.length(); j++) {

                                JSONObject jsonObjectSubCategories = jsonArraySubCategories.getJSONObject(j);

                                subCatId = jsonObjectSubCategories.getInt("id");

                                subCategory = jsonObjectSubCategories.getString("title");

                                Log.d("CATEGORY: ", subCategory);

                                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                map.put("title", subCategory);
                                map.put("id", subCatId + "");
                                myArrList.add(map);
                            }
                        }

                        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
                        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), myArrList,
                                R.layout.activity_show, new String[]{"title"},
                                new int[]{R.id.tv_column_name});

                        spinnerSubcategoriesList.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

                        spinnerSubcategoriesList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                String selectedSubCategory = myArrList.get(position).get("title").toString();

                                //DIST_ID = (int) (spinnerSubcategoriesList.getSelectedItemId() + 1);

                                //populateCompanies(DIST_ID);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(request);
}
```

Comment: try to use Gson, it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Describe data model

```
class DataItem {
     String id;
     String title;
     List<DataItem> subCategories;
}

class DataContent {
     List<DataItem> companyTypes;
     List<DataItem> citiesList;
     List<DataItem> brandsList;
     List<DataItem> categoriesList;
}

class DataResponse {
     Boolean success;
     Integer code;
     String message;
     DataContent content;  
}
```

And just use Gson to parse your response

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
     DataResponse dataResponse = gson.fromJson(response, DataResponse.class);
     ...
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your response! Sir i already done most of things. The spinners are populated but i am confused how to use if-condition when user select an item from 1st spinner and it populates the other spinner with its respective array. The id of an item is already passed to the method as argument. The problem is in the 2nd for-loop inside the 2nd method. Please resolve my problem. i am stuck here.